# why esper_ext timed does not filter out old entries

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I need help with understanding of the win_ext window in Esper (CEP). I'm wondering why older (first 2) events still popup on the update-method even though they have been "expired"

```
    public class MyCepTest {

    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("starting");
        MyCepTest ceptest = new MyCepTest();
        ceptest.execute();
        System.out.println("end");
    }

    public void execute() throws Exception{
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.addEventType(MyPojo.class);        
        EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(config);
        EPAdministrator admin = epService.getEPAdministrator();

        EPStatement x1 = admin.createEPL(win);
        EPStatement x2 = admin.createEPL(win2);        

        x1.setSubscriber(this);
        x2.setSubscriber(this);

        EPRuntime runtime = epService.getEPRuntime();

        ArrayList<MyPojo> staffToSendToCep = new ArrayList<MyPojo>();
        staffToSendToCep.add(new MyPojo(1, new Date(1490615719497L)));
        staffToSendToCep.add(new MyPojo(2, new Date(1490615929497L)));

        for(MyPojo pojo : staffToSendToCep){
            runtime.sendEvent(pojo);    
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("round 2...");//why two first Pojos are still found? Shouldn't ext_timed(pojoTime.time, 300 seconds) rule them out?

        staffToSendToCep.add(new MyPojo(3, new Date(1490616949497L)));        

        for(MyPojo pojo : staffToSendToCep){
            runtime.sendEvent(pojo);    
        }        
    }

    public void update(Map<String,Object> map){
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    public static String win = "create window fiveMinuteStuff.win:ext_timed(pojoTime.time, 300 seconds)(pojoId int, pojoTime java.util.Date)";    
    public static String win2 = "insert into fiveMinuteStuff select pojoId,pojoTime from MyPojo";
}

class MyPojo{
    int pojoId;
    Date pojoTime;
    MyPojo(int pojoId, Date date){
        this.pojoId = pojoId;
        this.pojoTime = date;
    }

    public int getPojoId(){
        return pojoId;
    }
    public Date getPojoTime(){
        return pojoTime;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return pojoId+"@"+pojoTime;
    }
}
```

I've been puzzled with this for a while and help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

See the processing model in docs. http://espertech.com/esper/release-6.0.1/esper-reference/html/processingmodel.html 
All incoming insert-stream events are delivered to listeners and subscribers. regardless of your window. A window, if one is in the query at all, defines the subsets of events to consider and therefore defines what gets aggregated, pattern-matched or is available for iteration. Try "select * from MyPojo" for reference. My advice to read up on external time, see http://espertech.com/esper/release-6.0.1/esper-reference/html/api.html#api-controlling-time
Usually when you want "external time window" you want event time to drive engine time.